# Why Android Studio Cannot Connect To Internet?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

My android Studio Was working very well a few days ago, but after 5-6 days, i opened it to make an application and i saw that android studio does not solve dependencies! And then i understood that sdk manager does not work too! it shows installed platforms and build tools and ... but it does not show updates and not-installed packages! i tried these:

1. Disabling proxy
2. Using another proxy
3. Using vpn
4. Update android studio from 4 to 2021
5. Restore all android studio settings
6. Uninstalling ndk
7. Creating a new project
8. Open old project that has not any error or problem
9. Deleting cache and .AndroidStudio folder
   But problem not solved. When i try to build my project, this is my build results:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Whatsapp Tricks'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.10/google-services-4.3.10.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

even if i dont open any project, and just by going to android studio settings, sdk manager does not show updates and...

Comment: if its a gradle problem maybe you should share build.gradle for both module and project

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin check this

Comment: Check the local firewall.